# using Guava BiMap in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, collections, guava

it's my first time i will use this library.

to explain my problem let's take this tiny example:

```
package javaapplication7;


import com.google.common.collect.BiMap;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;


public class JavaApplication7 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BiMap<Integer, Integer> biMap = HashBiMap.create();

    biMap.put(0, 0);
    biMap.put(2, 1);
    biMap.inverse().put(1,3);

    System.out.println(biMap.get(0));
    System.out.println(biMap.get(2));
    System.out.println(biMap.inverse().get(1));

    }

}
```

the result of this program is :

> 0
>
> null
>
> 3

Normally for the second print i should get **1** , could someone explain to me why i get a null value ?

In My program i should put some integer  in the map without a specific order , how can i do that?

I want to get **0 1 3** result for the preceding example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By inserting a **key** `1` to an **inversed** bimap view you actually overwrote a **value** `1` you had mapped earlier (i.e. in "normal" `biMap` there's no key `2` anymore, but under `3` there's value `1`). Just see what's happening your `biMap` after each operation:

```
biMap.put(0, 0);
System.out.println(biMap); // {0=0}
biMap.put(2, 1);
System.out.println(biMap); // {0=0, 2=1}
final Integer previousValue = biMap.inverse().put(1, 3);
System.out.println(biMap); // {0=0, 3=1}
System.out.println(previousValue); // 2
```